# Is it possible to pay for the bus at Skopje airport with euros or a credit card?

Tags: money, macedonia, balkans

Some friends and I are visiting Skopje next week. We want to take the bus from the airport to the city centre. I've read many times that you can pay nearly everywhere in Macedonia with euros. Is this also true for bus rides in general, but especially for the ride from the airport to the city?

Has someone some experience to share when it comes to paying with credit cards in Macedonia? How is the general acceptance in restaurants and stores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been there and it was good. Bus from the airport can be paid with euros, as in the most restaurants in Skopje and Ohrid. Credit cards are also accepted nearly everywhere, but not on the airport bus. As the course of the "Denare" is bound to the euro, you can exchange it in the city centre to really good exchange-rates with an absolute minimum of loss.

Comment: (+1) My impression is that you could pay in euros just about anywhere, including in small towns in the south which saw far fewer visitors from abroad than Ohrid. Are you just being careful or did you encounter a place that would not take euros?

Comment: we did encounter few places. Smaller takeaways far from the city center

Comment: I would rather recommend to take cash from ATM either in the airport or in the city in order to have Denars (Also, in my case, it was better to exchange by card rate, not ATM proposed). It makes you more resilient to all unpredictable situations you can encounter.